# kubeadm join failure, error execution phase kubelet-start: error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes

When join node : 
`sudo kubeadm join 172.16.7.101:6443 --token 4mya3g.duoa5xxuxin0l6j3 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:bba76ac7a207923e8cae0c466dac166500a8e0db43fb15ad9018b615bdbabeb2`

The outputs:

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
[kubelet-start] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.14" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Activating the kubelet service
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
error execution phase kubelet-start: error uploading crisocket: timed out waiting for the condition
```

And `systemctl status kubelet`:

```
node@node:~$ sudo systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-04-17 06:20:56 UTC; 12min ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
 Main PID: 26716 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 16 (limit: 1111)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─26716 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml -

Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.022384   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.073969   26716 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Node: Unauthorized
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.122820   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.228838   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.273153   26716 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:442: Failed to list *v1.Service: Unauthorized
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.330578   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.431114   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.473501   26716 reflector.go:126] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Unauthorized
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.531294   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
Apr 17 06:33:38 node kubelet[26716]: E0417 06:33:38.632347   26716 kubelet.go:2244] node "node" not found
```

To `Unauthorized` I checked at master with `kubeadm token list`, token is valid.
So what's the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to confirm, node hasn't been added to the cluster, right? Can you try to reload your kubelet config `sudo kubeadm upgrade node config --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --kubelet-version v1.13.4 -v8` Just put your kubelet version

Answer (score 2):

Please verify pre and post installation steps [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/):
 
Please verify also the status of your services enabled and running, docker env.

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl enable kubelet
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Are the results the same if you run init command with **--ignore-preflight-errors=all**
For more details please use also "**journalctl -u kubelet**"
Having more details from your logs, please take a look at "*github - kubeadm/issues*" [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues):
Please provide more details about you env in order to recreate this issue and share with your additional findings.

Could you please perform another test and run **kubeadm init** on your worker node, in the same way as on the first node (in short please create second master node) just to verify your working env.

Comment: command `journalctl -u kubelet` output is : Apr 03 09:43:36 node kubelet[2947]: F0403 09:43:36.835732    2947 server.go:193] failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet conf, I checked file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml is exist.

Comment: Updated - please perform test describe above.

Answer (score 2):

on worker nodes doing

```
sudo kubeadm reset
```

and then rejoining will solve this issue